# Adding A phonegap plugin that doesn't use plugman

Tags: cordova

Anyone know what the best way is to add a Phonegap / Cordova plugin that doesn't work with the phonegap local add plugin (plugman). I've tired manually updating the config.xml file, but I feel I'm missing somethings and the documentation on cordova 3.1 doesn't tell anything about what files are modified to make plugins "work".

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/ExtractZipFile

The is the repo I'm trying to utilize. I saw a similar post here here. I can download the repo fine as a zip, but then how would I go about adding this so it actually works.

In nut shell if I add my own custom plugin what files in cordova 3.1 do I need to modify to actually load it and make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update your `config.xml` to read something like:

   ```xml
   <feature name="ExtractZipFilePlugin" >
       <param name="ios-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ExtractZipFile"/>
   </feature>
   ```
2. Add a block to `cordova_plugins.js`:

   ```js
   {
       "file": "plugins/cordova/ZipPlugin.js",
       "id": "org.apache.cordova.extractZipFile",
       "clobbers": [
           "extractZipFile"
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Surround your plugin (in this case `ZipPlugin.js`) with a header

   ```js
   cordova.define("org.apache.cordova.extractZipFile", function(require, exports, module) {
   ```

   and a footer

   ```js
   });
   ```

You might need to adjust the exact id's here and there, but these are the basic steps to manually include a plugin into Cordova 3+.

Comment: Thanks I found this awhile ago and didn't get back here:) - That's what I need to do.